# Possible to generate links inside doxygen startuml/enduml section?

Tags: doxygen, plantuml

I have PlantUML configured to run from doxygen, and it is able to generate a simple diagram with a single class:

```
\startuml
class MyClass
\enduml
```

If I modify this to add a link to a url, clicking on the class in the UML works fine:

```
\startuml
class MyClass [[https://www.google.com]]
\enduml
```

I'd like have doxygen generate links so that clicking on the UML graph nodes takes the user to the documentation for the class, but clicking on `MyClass` in the following navigates me to `\link`:

```
\startuml
class MyClass [[\link MyClass]]
\enduml
```

I'd guess this is because the `\startuml ... \enduml` block is sent to PlantUML without being parsed by doxygen. Is there any way to make link generation work in this case?

If I remember correctly, `\link` and `\ref` were resolved inside `\dot ... \enddot` on a project I worked on years ago, and I'm wondering if there's a reason why this couldn't work inside `\startuml ... \enduml` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen does not interpret the input between the `\startuml` and `\enduml` tag, so it is, currently, not possible.

The fact that a `https` address works is due to the fact that it is handled by plantuml directly.